# Helix Server - Unable to see segmented files in IPhone folder during stream

Tags: video, stream, helix-server

I've configured my Helix Server as per the documentation: http://helixforum.realnetworks.com/he...

I am attempting to view a stream on a BlackBerry 9900. My video files are in the content/Iphone-src directory.

When I attempt to load a stream on my BlackBerry, the IPhone folder nor the Iphone-src directory are loaded with segmentation files (as it describes in the troubleshooting section of the initially mentioned page).

I was successfully able to stream a file that was ~60 megabytes in size and ~20 minutes in length, but I'm having issues with files 400 megabytes and 30 min to 1 hr long.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by talking with Helix Support.

Apparently my files were not encoded in the correct way to segment when placed in the iPhone-src folder.

After following these practices: http://helixforum.realnetworks.com/helix_help_center/topics/what_are_some_best_practices_for_encoding_content, I was able to get streams up and running.

I used HandBrake to encode my media.

Thanks,

Parth